# GraphQL/Sequelize : SQL alias

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-server

Technologies in use:

- Apollo-server-express for graphQL
- Sequelize to connect to SQL Server

I have inherited a database where fields don't follow any naming convention. Some have spaces and special characters. To avoid any issue, I used an SQL alias for these fields in the resolver queries :

```
const productAttributes = [
  'SAP', 
  ['Unit/V', 'UnitVol']];

...

  Query: {
    product: async (parent, {SAP} , { models }) => {
      const result = await models.Product.find( {
        where: {
          SAP: SAP
        },
        attributes:productAttributes,
      });
      return result;
    },
...
```

GraphQL schema is set to be :

```
type Product {
    SAP: String!
    UnitVol: Int
}
```

When executing the query from the playground, the field "SAP" coming from the model is well filled up, but the field alias "UnitVol" is set to null (see the image [GraphQL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmnvV.png)).

Looking in detail, Sequelize well executes the following SQL statement :

```
Executing (default): SELECT [SAP], [Unit/V] AS [UnitVol] FROM [product codes] WHERE [product codes].[SAP] = N'22736';
```

The Query result described above returns the values with the alias (extract of console.log(result)):

```
product codes {
  dataValues:
   { SAP: '22736',
     UnitVol: 9 }
 },
```

So it seems that there is a missing link between the SQL alias returned by the resolver and the graphQL schema. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: _____________________________

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution :

Instead of returning the sequelize result, I return the 'datavalues' array in the result:

```
return !result ? [] : result.dataValues;
```

I had to control that the result is not null (no entry for the graphQL request). If anyone has a cleaner answer, I'll be happy to test it! Thanks.